# Fetching user photos from Instagram when username contain dot (.)

Tags: php, laravel

May be silly question but I'm trying to make simple fetcher from instagram username. So far it is working great except when in the username has dot (.)

For example `user.name` return nothing but `username`, `user_name` are returning proper results. I so far have this simple code in laravel

```
public function index(Request $request)
{
    $items = [];

    if($request->has('username')){

        $client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client;
        $url = sprintf('https://www.instagram.com/%s/media', $request->input('username'));
        $response = $client->get($url);
        $items = json_decode((string) $response->getBody(), true)['items'];

    }
    //dd($items);
    return view('fetcher',compact('items'));
}
```

Can someone explain why this happen?

Comment: try this one  str_replace('.', '%2E', $request->input('username'));

Comment: It's still empty array

Comment: replace the dot with underscore try this one  str_replace('.', '_', $request->input('username'));

Comment: If I have user.name and replace the dot with underscore it's become user_name which is another user or not existing one

Answer (score 0):

Check like this, in laravel may be `.` is going to check nested value

```
$test_request = $request->request;
if(array_key_exists("username",$test_request)){
```

Comment: replace `if($request->has('username')){` with given code

Comment: Now it doesn't matter what username I've enter doesn't show anything